# Selenium Source Missing Login Fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with Python to log into an ESPN page:

http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/scoreboard?leagueId=34467&matchupPeriodId=1

When you go to this page it pops up a login box but Selenium can't seem to find the fields for it.

Here's my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/scoreboard leagueId=34467&matchupPeriodId=1')
username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('XXXXX')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('XXXXX')
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_name('submit')
submit_button.click()
```

When I view the page source in Chrome myself I see the form:

```
<table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="bodyCopy"><tr>
<td width=15%><b>MEMBER NAME:</b></td>
<td width=1%>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="username" size="16" maxlength="64" value="" class="select">            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>PASSWORD:</b></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" size="16" maxlength="25" value="" class="select"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="select"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

However, when I use...

```
page = driver.page_source
```

...the form is missing entirely. I can see the same form in the browser window that Selenium opens up though, it's just missing from the source. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that the *login form is inside an `iframe`* and you need to switch to it:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("disneyid-iframe")
```

And, the second issue is that the form is loaded dynamically. You need to [explicitly wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the username field to show up before starting to log in (well, as a human would do):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.field-username-email input")))

print(driver.page_source)
```

Note that your locators point to non-existing elements. Use instead:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.field-username-email input")
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.field-password input")
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(., 'Log In')]")
```

Comment: I switched to the iframe and put in the explicit wait but I'm still getting "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}"

Comment: The username worked but the password field still isn't found.

Comment: @TonyTrozzo yeah, I had multiple updates, check it out now. Thanks.

Comment: Worked now! Thank you very much!